# how to set focus to a specific section when the page loads and make the browser scroll to that position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am working with aps.net and vb.net

In my application after submitting the web form (**application.aspx**) users are redirected into another (**application_complete.aspx**) page .

The webform in  application.aspx page is very long. and user has to scroll down a lot to complete the form and submit. Problem is after submitting the the form (appplication.aspx) the application_complete.aspx page also becomes very long (same size as the application.aspx) although there is not much content in it and makes the browser automatically position at same place (bottom of the page). Therefore user has to scroll up to read the message. which is very irritating for the users. (see picures)

**picture1 : (appplication.aspx)**
[image]

**picture2: application_complete.aspx**
[image]

**What I require**
I want to make  the page (application_complete.aspx) position at the top of the page when it loads and set focus at the message section of that page.

This is my application_complete.aspx page code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/c/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="application-complete.aspx.vb" Inherits="c_application_complete" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/c/MasterPage.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" Runat="Server">


<h2>Thank you! we have now received your application</h2>

<div class="btn-wrapper">
    <a target="_parent" href="<%= Master.EmployerCareersHome %>" class="btn v-view-all">View other open positions</a>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

and this is my application_complete.aspx.vb code

```
Partial Class c_application_complete
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
```

I have tried adding the following script in application_complete.aspx page and by giving a id to the div section.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#<%= dvbtn.ClientID %>").focus();

    });
</script>

</asp:Content>
```

and in application_complete.aspx.vb page.

```
    Protected Sub PageLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

         Page.SetFocus(dvbtn)

    End Sub
```

but thats not working.

For your information

1. the whole webform and its all functionality is in a iframe .is it possible to make  parent web page scroll to a specific position (at the top) from an iframe.
2. Though there is not much content in application_complete page still because of long form (in application.aspx page) this page(application_complete) also becomes long.and if someone refreshes it then the page gets back to its original size and focuses on the top position. but refreshing causes the re submission of the form so can't do that.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: somthing like this?? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips I am giving example of URL not the content it shows. The page scrolls to required section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you page put an anchor something like:

```
<a name="loadtohere" />
```

Then in your redirect, send the page to:

page.aspx#loadtohere

EDIT:

OK, in your source code file add the html from above:

```
<a name="loadtohere" />
```

Then in your code behind:

```
// Create the redirect link (better way of creating your string)
Dim redirect = String.Format("application-complete.aspx?e={0}&b={1}&i={2}&hp={3}&hI={4}#loadtohere, Vacancy.EmployerID, CInt(Request("b")), Vacancy.ID, Request("hp"), Request("hI"))

// Redirect to the page
Response.Redirect(redirect)
```

The "loadtohere" text can be changed to whatever you want, it is just the name of the anchor to move the page to when it loads.

Comment: Response.Redirect("application-complete.aspx?e=" & Vacancy.EmployerID & "&b=" & CInt(Request("b")) & "&i=" & Vacancy.ID & "&hp=" & Request("hp") & "&hI=" & Request("hI"))    -   can you elaborate please. i m very poor in this coading. this is my redirect code.

Comment: you saved me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that my element wasn't receiving focus was because it is a `<div>` and not an actual `<button>` element. `<div>` elements by default aren't picked up as part of the tab order so they don't generally receive focus at all.

So i solved the focusing problem by adding a tabindex attribute to my div element.

```
<div class="btn-wrapper" id="dvbtn" runat="server" tabindex="0" autofocus>
    <a target="_parent" href="<%= Master.EmployerCareersHome %>" class="btn v-view-all">View other open positions</a>
</div>
```

and with the script

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent" runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#<%= dvbtn.ClientID %>").focus();

         });
   </script>

</asp:Content>
```

setfocus also solved the problem of scrolling.